# How to add second product to cart in Shopify from product page

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I'm using Shopify and  am trying to add the options to add gift wrap and a carry case to products being bought.

I can use the `item.properties` to ask the user for the choice and show that in the cart.

I now want to add an additional product to the cart if `item.properties` is set to "gift wrap" or "carry case".

This code is placed in the product-template.liquid but does not work:

```
{% for property in item.properties %}
                {% if property.last == "Gift Wrap" %}
               <p>This would add gift wrap.</p>
            <script>
                jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {
                updates: {
                32005672697928: 1
                }
                });
            </script>
              {% endif %}
              {% if property.last == "Carry Strap" %}
                <p>This would add carry strap.</p>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            {% endunless %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem the code you have was intended to be used on the product page. It looks like it should be placed on the cart page within the `{% for item in cart.items %} ... {% endfor %}` loop.

Also, this code will add only 1 wrap product, even if customers add 2+ wrapped items. I would change the code to something like the below:

```
{%- assign numWrappedItems = 0 -%}
{%- for item in cart.items -%}
  {%- for property in item.properties -%}
    {%- if property.last == "Gift Wrap" -%}
      {%- assign numWrappedItems = numWrappedItems | plus: item.quantity -%}
      {%- break -%}
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endfor -%}

  ...
{%- endfor -%}

{%- if numWrappedItems > 0 -%}
<script>
jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {
  updates: {
    32005672697928: {{ numWrappedItems }}
  }
});
</script>
```

I hope the above makes sense.

Comment: Thank you.Unfortunatley that still doesn't work. It seems like the script to update cart is the part that doesn't work. I put it on the cart page like you mentioned. Could it be because am in preview mode?

Comment: Can you leave a link to your website/preview to check that? What theme do you use?